# Time complexity of a special DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

its known that DFS time complexity is `O(|V|+|E|)` .
Suppose each vertex `v` has a positive weight `w(v)`. I want to change the DFS algorithm such that when we have "exertion" of which vertex we need to add to the empty stack-we will add the most weighted vertex.

exertion means- when the stack is empty and we need to choose a vertex to start\contiue with. (sorry for being unformal)

example:
if we have this directed graph:

```
A->B->C D->E F->G->H
```

and `w(D)>w(A)>w(F)`, this new DFS on the graph will traverse this order:

```
D E A B C F G H
```

what is the time complexity of the new DFS i suggested?

Comment: its a soloution for a probelm i have and i just need to be sure about the time complexity of this soloution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the next vertex, you need to sort the outgoing edges at the current vertex. Across all the vertices you need to sort a total of `|E|` elements, which will add to your complexity `O(|E|log|E|)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just sort all vertices in the beginning, and execute dfs through that order.

So it's VlogV + E.

I don't understand why we have to sort 'outgoing edges' in the above answer.